# Seemingly over-complicated CSS list styling that SHOULD be easy

Tags: css, html-lists

I need to create a style for ordered lists that follows this format:

```
(a)    List Item 1
(b)    List Item 2
    (1)    List Item 2.1
    (2)    List Item 2.2
        (i)    List Item 2.2.1
        (ii)   List Item 2.2.2
```

Unfortunately, `list-style-type` doesn't work because there are no options that show the numbers as listed above, with parentheses.

LOTS of researching has brought about nothing but ugly hacks, for example:

```
ol {
    list-style-type: none;
}

ol>li:before {
    content: "(" counter(lvl1, lower-alpha) ") ";
}

ol li {
    counter-increment: lvl1;
}

ol ol>li:before {
    content: "(" counter(lvl2, decimal) ") ";
}

ol ol>li {
    counter-increment: lvl2;
}

ol ol ol>li:before {
    content: "(" counter(lvl3, lower-roman) ") ";
}

ol ol ol>li {
    counter-increment: lvl3;
}
```

which works to some extent, removing the list numbering with `list-style-type: none;` and inserting the number surrounded with parentheses at the beginning of the `li`.  This makes modifying other related styling horrific, as I can't figure out how to line things up nicely etc (I don't think its even possible).  It also makes `list-style-position` redundant, because the numbers are ALWAYS inside the `li`.

Basically, I'm looking for a way to reproduce this kind of list numbering in CSS: (note text alignment etc)

[image: List Numbering Example]

ANY help VERY MUCH appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there.

Since you're removing `list-style`, you can restore the position of the counters by applying padding to the list items and then pulling the counters into that padding with a negative margin (or one of many similar techniques e.g. hanging indent)

```
li {
    padding: 2em;
}

li:before {
    /* Take counter out of flow and pull it into padding space */
    float: left;
    margin-left: -2em;
}
```

You also need to sprinkle some `counter-reset` into the mix for each level of `ol` nesting.

JSFiddle showing a full working example with all the nesting code here: http://jsfiddle.net/thefrontender/tzzbh/2/

Comment: Thanks for the jsfiddle demo!  That answers a couple of questions I had, but I'm doing this on a page with a tinyMCE editor, which seems to add nested lists as direct children of the list object - not inside a `li` - and this means your example has no indentation at all :(

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the markup you're working with? Another JSFiddle perhaps? Should just be a matter of tweaking the padding on `ol` and `li` instead of just on `li` … even if tinyMCE is producing invalid HTML :)

Comment: Tried putting a proper SSCCE example in a JSFiddle for ya, but I have to specify the CSS filename in tinyMCE initialization, and JSFiddle of course won't have the CSS file there.  This is the best I could do: http://jsfiddle.net/whiletrue/Jq7tU/  
Note the tinyMCE.init() functions "content-css" value.  This is what I'm talking about.  However, I've thrown an example list into a div - same effect really.

Comment: Brilliant!  Figured it out thanks to your example:
`.mce-content-body ol {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
 padding-left: 4em;
    counter-reset: l1;
}

.mce-content-body > ol {
 padding-left: 0;
}

.mce-content-body li {
    padding-left: 4em;
    margin-top: .3em;
}

.mce-content-body li:before {
    float: left;
    margin-left: -4em;
}`